# How many times to use set.seed(123)

Tags: r

I have 60 lines of code. Throughout the code there are several calls to random number generators including `rnorm()`. Is it enough to put `set.seed(x)` in the very beginning of the code or do I need to set.seed every time random number generation occurs in the code?

Comment: See also: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58890/set-seed-before-each-code-block-or-once-per-project

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It really depends on how you foresee the code changing in the future.

If you expect that you will be including commands at an earlier point in the code that will require random number generation and you want to replicate the results you were getting earlier *before* inserting that code, you should use `set.seed()` at the appropriate points in your code.

Example:

```
set.seed(1)
A <- rnorm(10)
B <- rnorm(10)
C <- rnorm(10) ## I always want "C" to be the results I get here

set.seed(1)
AA <- rnorm(10); BB <- rnorm(10); CC <- rnorm(10)

identical(A, AA)
# [1] TRUE
identical(B, BB)
# [1] TRUE
identical(C, CC)
# [1] TRUE

set.seed(1)
A <- rnorm(10); B <- rnorm(10); C <- rnorm(10)

set.seed(1)
AA <- rnorm(10); BB <- rnorm(10); BA <- rnorm(10); CC <- rnorm(10)

identical(A, AA)
# [1] TRUE
identical(B, BB)
# [1] TRUE
identical(C, CC)
# [1] FALSE
```

In the above, if I wanted "C" to always be the same no matter what comes before it, I should set the seed just before that.

Note that since I hadn't reset the seed before creating `C` or `CC`, and there is a new function requiring random number generation between `BB` and `CC` in the second example, the values for `C` and `CC` are now different. If you wanted them to be the same, you would have to insert another `set.seed` just before creating `C` and `CC`, as follows:

```
set.seed(1)
A <- rnorm(10)
B <- rnorm(10)
set.seed(2)
C <- rnorm(10) ## I always want "C" to be the results I get here

set.seed(1)
AA <- rnorm(10); BB <- rnorm(10); BA <- rnorm(10);
set.seed(2)
CC <- rnorm(10)

identical(A, AA)
# [1] TRUE
identical(B, BB)
# [1] TRUE
identical(C, CC)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: @user1984076 yes. Look at `set.seed(1); runif(4); runif(4)` and then `set.seed(1); runif(8)`.

Comment: but if I set seed just before CC then it will be identical to AA right?

Comment: With `set.seed(X)` you will always get the same sequence of numbers starting at (virtual) index 1. With next set.seed with the same X you just reset the position. See this `set.seed(1); A = rnorm(20); set.seed(1); B = c(rnorm(10),rnorm(5),rnorm(5)); identical(A,B);` Comparison `identical(C, CC)` fails because some random numbers in the sequence have been consumed by BA.

Comment: @TomasGreif, yes, exactly.

Comment: Summary: For the most part, only needed just once in a particular script. I sometimes include it more than once if I think I'll be breaking the script up into smaller scripts later and I want each portion of the script to be reproducible as a standalone script.